# stackexchange.com activity tab: wide images cause the width of the page to be increased

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, activity

I just posted a question with a wide image, and it causes the page to become wider in the [activity tab on StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/%E1%94%95%E1%96%BA%E1%98%8E%E1%95%8A?tab=activity):

> [image]
> [image]

However, on MSE (here), in the activity tab, the image is properly made smaller:

[image]

Because there is a CSS rule `max-width:630px;`. Can that (or similar) be added to SE.com?